# Converting SSM Value To Number

Tags: amazon-sns, serverless-framework

I am trying to deploy an SNS subscription through Serverless Framework to AWS using a range filter policy. My resource definition looks something like this:

```
      MySusbscription:
        Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
        Properties:
          TopicArn:
            Ref: MyTopic
          Endpoint: !GetAtt MyQueue.Arn
          Protocol: sqs
          RawMessageDelivery: true
          FilterPolicy:
            percentage:
              - numeric:
                - '>='
                - ${ssm:/path/to/ssm/key}
          RedrivePolicy:
            deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt MyQueueDlq.Arn
```

The problem is that Serverless pulls all SSM values as strings, so the compiled version of the deployment config will be:

```
              - numeric:
                - '>='
                - '0.25'
```

This will fail to deploy as SNS requires `0.25` to be a number instead of a string. Serverless has a `strToBool` function, but I haven't seen documentation to indicate there is an equivalent function for converting to a number/float.

I'm sure I can get around this by using env variables, but we store all configurations in SSM and I'm hoping to not have to do a one-off just to get past this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution is not the cleanest one, but will work for sure.

In the directory define your custom JS file `ssmToNumber.js` with following script:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports = async (serverless) => {
  # Setup AWS SDK with region and profile
  const { region } = serverless.processedInput.options;

  AWS.config.update({ region });
  if (serverless.processedInput.options['aws-profile']) {
    process.env.AWS_PROFILE = serverless.processedInput.options['aws-profile'];
  }
  const ssm = new AWS.SSM({ apiVersion: '2014-11-06' });

  # Get SSM params details from serverless.yml
  const ssmKey = serverless.service.custom.ssmKeys.percentageNumericThreshold.path;
  const decryption = serverless.service.custom.ssmKeys.percentageNumericThreshold.decryption;
  
  # Get SSM parameter value and convert it to int
  const result = await ssm.getParameter({
    Name: ssmKey,
    WithDecryption: decryption,
  }).promise();

  if (result.Parameter) {
    return parseInt(result.Parameter.Value, 10);
  }
  throw new Error(`Failed to read SSM parameter for key ${ssmKey}`);
};
```

Now in `serverless.yml` define following values:

```
custom:
  ssmKeys:
    percentageNumericThreshold:
      path: '/path/to/ssm/key'
      decryption: false
```

And in the place, where you want to have your number value from SSM, simply invoke it this way:

```
      FilterPolicy:
        percentage:
          - numeric:
            - '>='
            - ${file(./ssmToNumber.js)}
```

### How it works?

Serverless Framework can start any JavaScript/TypeScript file during the build and put it's output into `serverless.yml` file.

And this is exactly what we do here. We define our `ssmToNumber.js` script, that simply reads SSM parameter from SSM and then converts it to integer and returns the value.

It knows which SSM path to use, thanks to the `custom.ssmKeys` section in `serverless.yml` file.

Of course if you want to customise `ssmToNumber.js` file, to make it more verbose and fault tolerant, then you simply need to edit the JavaScript file.

### Another, more elegant way

It requires more work. Check out the official example for [Serverless with Typescript](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/plugins/create/templates/aws-nodejs-typescript/serverless.ts).

As you can see, it's possible to use `serverless.ts` or `serverless.js` instead of YAML file.

It would require from you some work about refactoring existing YML file, but writing helper function, that would convert it to number, is very easy and elegant way to achieve your use case.

It have some downsides, like problems with including directly other YAML templates, but still you can define your CloudFormation YAML templates in separate files and then simply import those using `import` call from TS/JS code.

Comment: I like the idea of using a simple JS reference variable. I ended up avoiding the issue by changing my subscription so that the numerical filter was no longer needed, but still interested in getting this to work. I tried your version, but couldn't get it to work. Will still give it another try, but also hoping to have a more generic solution, or even avoid the JS SSM retrieval and just pass in a parameter to the JS code (something like `${file(./strToInt.js)}` + param), but haven't seen examples where it can take in a parameter other than `serverless`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's impossible to pass a parameter inside, that's why I assign the data to `custom.ssmKeys` so later it's possible to read it using `serverless` object.
The reason JS SSM retrieval is needed is simple: JS script is started before Serverless resolves SSM parameters using `${ssm:/path}` syntax, that's why you must do it in JS, otherwise you don't have value to `parseInt`.

Comment: And also about problems with this script, it might be connected with incorrect AWS CLI configuration. It's easy to debug those JS scripts, if you: mock `serverless` object and simply let it use `aws-sdk`, then testing it with Jest is simple.
There is a second, more advanced way of debugging, where you simply setup debug run configuration in your IDE for `npm (or yarn) run deploy` and setup deploy script in `package.json`. IDE debugger will connect to the Serverless process and will break on breakpoints from JS file, so you don't have to mock anything.

Comment: And also try to debug it with `sls print` CLI, it simply runs all of the JS scripts and links external files, then outputs the final YAML file into console. It's very helpful for debugging :)